# Parse.Promise.as() not returning a Promise

Tags: parse-platform, promise

Having an issue with the Parse Javascript SDK running a backend job.

I have a function that returns a different promise depending on conditions. In the case that neither condition is met, I'd like to return a "dummy" promise that doesn't do anything:

```
function myFunction() {

  if (condition1)
    return somePromise();

  else if (condition2)
    return someOtherPromise();

  else
    return ???
}
```

I tried returning `Parse.Promise.as()`, but this fails when neither condition is met:

```
E2015-03-18T21:31:50.410Z] v41: Ran job checkup with:
Input: {}
Failed with: TypeError: Object false has no method 'then'
  at jobs/checkup.js:18:73
  at null.<anonymous> (Parse.js:3:19012)
  at e (Parse.js:2:6670)
  at Parse.js:2:7423
  at g (Parse.js:2:7160)
  at c.extend.then (Parse.js:2:7408)
  at Parse.js:3:18989
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function.x.each.x.forEach (Parse.js:1:661)
  at Parse.js:3:18966
```

**Edit:** Here is where the function is being called:

```
function checkup() { 

  return Parse.Cloud.job("checkup", function(request, status) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("active", true);
    query.each(function(user) {
      return myFunction().then(function() {
        return user.save();
      });

    }).then(function() {
      status.success('success');
    }); 
  });
}
```

Comment: The error implies that myFunction is returning false, and the caller is trying to invoke then() on it.  Is it possible that your somePromise() or someOtherPromise() functions are actually returning false and not a promise?  It would seem so.  Parse.Promise.as().then() should work just fine.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of that exception?

Comment: `return Parse.Promise.as(dummmyresult);` should be the way to go.

Comment: somePromise() and someOtherPromise() definitely return promises, because when the conditions are met, I can successfully call `myFunction().then()`.

Comment: @Bergi I've updated with the full stack trace

Comment: And `checkup.js` calls `myFunction()`? Can you show us the code of that call?

Comment: Updated with context

Comment: Can you `console.log` the object before you call `then` on it maybe? not sure how to debug cloud code.

Comment: Probably myFunction returns false check that out

Answer (score 1):

Returning `Parse.Promise.as()` is the correct path to follow, as it is a resolved promise.

The error is clearly stating that one of your promises is returning the bool value of `false`. Track down that and your problem is solved.